# Jquery: Use icons instead of buttons

Tags: jquery

How to use icons instead of buttons?

I have to regularly turn on and off the icons depending on user actions.

So I can easily change the image of the icon but how do I disable the click event.

I try to use "bind" and "unbind" but it causes me a lot of problems.

The accumulation of "bind" repeatedly invoke the same function.

I tried the method. One

Do you know a better way?

Thanks :)

Comment: Add a class (like `"disabled"`)... and then inside the click handler check with `hasClass()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the element:

```
x.addClass('disabled');
```

Enabling the element:

```
x.removeClass('disabled');
```

The click handler:

```
x.click(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) { return; }
    // continue normally
});
```